# Темизация формы входа Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

Пытаюсь темизировать форму входа, которая по умолчанию открывается по ссылке /user/login/

Делал  все как описано в [этой](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/overriding-themable-output/customizing-and-overriding-user-login-page-register-and) статье.
Добавил код в template.php

```
function aihal_theme() {
  $items = array();
    
  $items['user_login'] = array(
    'render element' => 'form',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'aihal') . '/templates',
    'template' => 'user-login',
    'preprocess functions' => array(
       'aihal_preprocess_user_login'
    ),
  );

  return $items;
}
function aihal_preprocess_user_login(&$vars) {
  $vars['intro_text'] = t('This is my awesome login form');
}
```

создал user-login.tpl.php

```
<p><?php print render($intro_text); ?></p>
<div class="aihal-user-login-form-wrapper">
  <?php print drupal_render_children($form) ?>
</div>
```

обновил кеш, зашел на страницу обновил и нечего не изменилось.

Гугил , но так и не нашел решения которое сработало бы у меня.
После того как получиться темизировать форму, именно поменять структуру html хочу вывести ее с помощью Modal Forms .